# Adding Facebook , Gmail Login to Own Website . Is it free?

Tags: facebook, gmail

I want to add facebook and gmail login for my application. Does facebook and gmail charge anything for providing login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is for "free". They however track your users as form of charge.